Modeling Transitive Preference
I've conducted a preference test twice on 10 subjects, presenting them with three options in all six pairwise combinations (AB, BA, CB, BC, AC, CA).
I need to determine the following: if each subject has a preference; if so, whether it is transitive (e.g., A>B>C but not C>A) and/or repeatable across both tests; how strong the preferences are; and whether the options' familiarity (familiar or unfamiliar) and/or type (X, Y, Z) tends to make a difference across all subjects and tests.
Here's my current plan:

Add up the time spent with each option for each subject. For each pairwise comparison (AB, BA, CA, etc.), the option that the subject spends more time with will be considered the preferred option.

Create functions to check the transitivity and repeatability of preferences across both tests.

Assess the strength of preferences by using repeated measures ANOVA or mixed-effects models to analyze the time spent with each option, summed over both tests, and factor in whether the preference is transitive and/or repeatable. Cases that are transitive, repeatable, and for which there is much more time spent with the preferred option will be the cases of strongest preference.

Use logistic regression or generalized linear mixed models (GLMM) to analyze the influence of familiarity and option type on preference outcomes.


I'm wondering:

How to create a preference strength score that factors in transitivity, repeatability, and time.

How to decide which statistical methods are most appropriate.



Human preferences are not transitive relations in general. Rather, you can estimate or model a probability that triples of options will be preferred transitively.

This R-package is probably relevant: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BradleyTerry2/index.html
